# Ext JS 4.2 creates multiple virtual script files

Tags: firebug, extjs4.2

When I use Ext JS 4.2 in my projects, it provokes me some problems:

- **Creates multiple virtual files** for scripts. There are single JavaScript functions in these files. These files names start with my main render file name and continue with `@conn0.source#`.. (e.g. if I have file named 'Photos', there would be virtual files named: 'Photos@conn0.source123', 'Photos@conn0.source124', 'Photos@conn0.source125', ...).

[image: Firebug 2.0.8 script file list]

- When I have opened Firebug (v2.0.8) in Firefox (last version: v36.0.4) and reload the page, the browser hangs and asks me to continue or stop the script. Though it works again after 1-2 minutes.

Does anyone know answers for these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug lists dynamically executed scripts up to a specific maximum number you can control via the [extensions.firebug.maxNumberOfDynamicScripts](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Preferences#maxNumberOfDynamicScripts) preference.

Note that it's a [known issue](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/867sRwxk6R0/discussion) that Firebug causes the browser to hang on pages with Ext JS scripts. This issue should be fixed with Firefox 37, which was released on March 31.